# How to implement shared resources in Pulumi

Tags: amazon-web-services, pulumi

I'm trying to understand how to implement Pulumi in our AWS environment.

I understand that a stack can be used to have the same resource structure for production and development, but that results in independant instances, which is great.

However we also have a shared management VPC where certain tools reside such as pgadmin, gitlab, monitoring tools,...

So what would be the best approach for that?

- Force a stack for that management project (if that is possible)?
- Put a constraint in code so that this management stuff is only deployed in production stack?

Or am I missing the approach of stacks here?

Answer (score 5):

Your first thought is the right way to go.
Deploy shared resources in their own stack(s) and use Stack References to share information across stacks.

These links discuss these concepts:
https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/organizing-stacks-projects/
https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/programming-model/#stack-references